# Prism.DRYIoc Cannot switch off ThrowOnRegisteringDisposableTransient

Tags: wpf, prism, dryioc

I have view with IDIsposable implemented and during registration, Prism throwing exception that it will not track this instance. I did the following:

```
var container = Container.GetContainer();

container.Rules.WithoutThrowOnRegisteringDisposableTransient();
```

But this did not help, because it does not switch corresponding property to false.
Please, help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got very limited DryIOC experience, but shouldn't the rules be set when creating the container?

I'd override `PrismApplication.CreateContainerRules`:

```
protected override Rules CreateContainerRules() => Rules.Default.WithAutoConcreteTypeResolution()
                                                                .With(Made.Of(FactoryMethod.ConstructorWithResolvableArguments)
                                                                .WithDefaultIfAlreadyRegistered(IfAlreadyRegistered.Replace)
                                                                .WithoutThrowOnRegisteringDisposableTransient());
```